Can depression be a reaction?
I practice Vipassana meditation and am currently going through a period of anhedonia and I am trying to understand if my depression is a sankhara or if it is simply a result of my mind reacting and not being equanimous in my everyday life. While practicing Vipassana I don't have a problem following the instructions or have an overly difficult time practicing equanimity so it doesn't make sense that I would be able to cause that much suffering in my every day life because of my reactivity. But then if it's not my mind reacting to something it means it has simply arisen for whatever cause. I find it difficult to navigate the personal accountability of what one experiences (I caused my depression by not living a fulfilling life, not providing for my needs etc) and my depression simply being caused by the inescapable suffering of life and/or sankharas. Because then it does mean that we can control our well being by changing something outside of ourselves which contradicts the idea that we are 100% responsible for the pain we carry, but that's not true is it? We are hurt and traumatised by the world and relationships and while we then have responsibility to not generate more suffering for ourselves we didn't cause the harm that was done to us in the first place which would mean that certain pain and sadness that we carry does not come from us.
I realise that ultimately, whether our suffering comes from a reaction, a sankhara or from wherever else the procedure of taking care of and approaching the suffering will be by the same technique according to Vipassana, namely through observing the sensations and by practicing equanimity. But is that enough? How do you know if you need to change things in your life to be able to be well? If you practice you might feel a sense of relief and a little more clarity but what if that's not enough to actually feel a sense of meaningfulness and a desire to take action, to do things? Hope this made sense, if anyone has any insight they'd like to share around this topic I'd be deeply appreciative, thank you.

Depression, like anger, is rooted in expectations: the world is not the way we expect it to be, and we either lash out others for messing things up, or lash inwards at ourselves for not doing things better.  What we eventually need to realize is that the way the world is isn't anyone's fault — no one is intentionally messing up, we're all just acting out of ignorance — and that as we (slowly) remove that ignorance, the world will (slowly, so slowly) improve. It probably won't become what we expect, but that's mainly because we will discover (and remove) the ignorance that's hidden in our expectations.
The difference between a reaction and a formation is mainly a matter of degree: formations are reactions that have solidified or crystalized into habits. If you treat it as a reaction (e.g., observe it the way you would an itch or an ache), the formation will dissolve over time.
If it troubles you, you can try what I think of as dual acceptance: accept that this is how the world is, and accept that it can and will change. If you can accept those, then all you need to do is keep making yourself a proper vector of change. That should bring some joy and purpose back into your practice.

You are separating reacting mind from sankhara, which is wrong. Sankhara is any conditioned phenomena. For example - if this action then that reaction else that reaction is also a sankhara.
Meditate on five things(it is difficult to meditate if you have a difficult wife, which is usually the case!!):

Metta : loving kindness or benevolence towards all. Be friendly towards all. Wish best for yourself. Wish happiness for your friends.Wish happiness for your enemies. Wish happiness for every being.
Karuna : Have compassion towards all because everyone is going to suffer, whether your friend or enemy. Have compassion to such an extent that if somebody disembowls you then you should not have any bad or cruel thoughts towards him or her.
Mudita: Be happy by counting your blessings. Be happy by counting the blessings of others including your enemies.
Equanimity : Be dispassionate by knowing the impermanence of all things. Impermanence of prosperity. Impermanence of beauty. Impermanence of pride. Impermanence of technology. Impermanence of air. Impermanence of water. Impermanence of fire. Impermanence of space. Impermanence of earth. That which is impermanent is suffering. Therefore is not fit to be called self. Therefore be dispassionate towards all including life.

Meditate on all the above one by one. Give like a week or month or year to each meditation topic. Be sincere and it will make you balanced and free you from depression.

I can't really see what the question is correctly so I will explain a few things and hope I hit it right.
Life, existence, sentience is suffering. Birth is suffering, sickness, ageing, death is suffering.
Living is suffering.
It may sound negative but this is exactly why we need to be strong and look at life logically and really understand that this place is a prison that causes us harm, not a joyous playground filled with lovely things and lovely people.
Now this on it's own can be depressing if one focuses solely on the problem but what we need to do is focus on the cure! And the cure is, the eightfold path.
Now you mentioned depression and anhedonia in the same sentence, so I am assuming your issue is not temporary sadness, a reactive depression for relative scenarios in live. I assume it is a mental health issue.
If you have clinical depression or schizophrenia, the sad thing is that they are illnesses. They are suffering in of themselves, as above "sickness is suffering". Latter being incurable and actually a physiological illness of the brain.
Illness is part of this sentience experience. Nobody can escape ageing, sickness and death. Even the Buddha himself died because of sickness.
All we can do is practice the eightfold path.
To break the eightfold path down to the 3 higher trainings, it is morality. Do no misdeeds and harm to oneself or others. Concentration/mindfulness. Practice satiphatanna in your daily life and samataha in meditation. Then wisdom, practice vipassana to inquire into reality.
Though here is not the right place to gain personal meditation advice. You would genuinely need to speak to someone, a more experienced monk in real life to gain adequate advice for your personal situation. From what you have written I think you are having an issue where you have jumped the gun and are doing work on/at the end of the path without building foundations.
One of the main reasons to practice sila, morality, the first 6 of the eightfold path, is so that we ourselves can live with an undisturbed mind free from guilt or unwholesome connection to things and others. Remaining unburdened. So maybe start looking there in your own situation.
Secondly I think it would probably be wiser to practice just simple samatha meditations to give your mind some rest and peace. Just doing basic breathing meditations, anapannasati can give your mind some well deserved rest and peace. You can also look into learning and practising satiphattana
Lastly I would say not to put too much pressure on yourself, Be light-hearted about things. Even just "fake it until you make it" by pretending to not be so concerned about things can change your mental make up from being heavy and clinging to things to just joyous and not concerned about anything. Over time of course.
Don't take things too seriously. It's not like we are getting out of this place alive right...
Exercise helps too. Which you can do while practising mindfulness.

0
"If you have clinical depression or schizophrenia, the sad thing is that they are illnesses."
Yes,they are. And like other illnesses, they have a cause; in this case a chemical imbalance in your brain. All the above advice is solid and should do you good. But treatment of the illness, i.e. medication, could help get you to a place where you can focus better on your practice; especially the Four Noble Truths and the Eightfold Path to cessation.

That is pseudo-science. As I said the latter, schizophrenia being a physiological issue with the brain. There is no cure for such ailment. Depression can be healed to an extent with meditation but not fully healed. Schizophrenia cannot even be treated, only acute periods of delusion/psychosis can be helped with drugs. Anti psychotics.

You're right. I did not make clear that I was referring only to depression (of which I have a profound and personal knowledge). I meant that depression can be treated and managed, similar to, e.g., diabetes. Sadly, you are also right in that  "Schizophrenia cannot even be treated".

The theories of Goenka do not necessarily correlate with the teachings of the Buddha. For example, the Buddha emphasised developing rapture/joy in meditation prior to equanimity.
Depression can certainly occur by being hurt and traumatised by the world and relationships. Therefore, a solution to this depression is to learn what unskilful conduct in relationships is, to avoid unskilful conduct in relationships, to learn what skilful conduct in relationships is and to develop skilful conduct in relationships (such as is explained in various Buddha suttas, including DN 31, AN 4.55 & AN 4.53). If it is not known what proper conduct is in relationships then it is unlikely meditation can be helpful. In MN 6, it is taught careful observance of ethical precepts is the foundation of all higher achievements in the spiritual/meditative life.
In addition, particularly for laypeople, the Buddha emphasised the practice of generosity & charity leads to happiness, strength, beauty & long life.
Other important aspects of Buddhism, in relation to general health, are proper eating of food & doing physical exercise. For example, during the Buddha's time, the monks walked great distances and also practiced walking meditation.
The Buddha never taught something, such as depression, is simply caused by the inescapable suffering of life. In AN 3.61, the Buddha explained believing in such types of fatalism results in inaction; "when one can't pin down as a truth or reality what should & shouldn't be done, one dwells bewildered & unprotected".
